# PHP articles and images issue

Tags: php

This is still not working, so I'm posting whole code here now...

```
<form id="contact-form" action="fileovi/dodaj_novost.php" method="post">
          <fieldset>
            <div class="coll-1">
              <div class="txt-form">Naslov[hr]</div>
              <label class="name">
                <input type="text" name="naslov_hr">
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="coll-1">
              <div class="txt-form">Naslov[en]</div>
              <label class="name">
                <input type="text" name="naslov_en">
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="coll-1">
              <div class="txt-form">Naslov[de]</div>
              <label class="name">
                <input type="text" name="naslov_de">
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="coll-1">
              <div class="txt-form">Link slike</div>
              <label class="name">
                <input type="file" name="image[]" enctype="multipart/form-data"/><br />
                <input type="file" name="image[]" enctype="multipart/form-data"/><br />
              <br>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="coll-big">
              <div class="txt-form"><center>Tekst[hr]</center></div>
              <label class="name">
                <textarea id="tekst" name="tekst_hr"></textarea>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="coll-big">
              <div class="txt-form"><center>Tekst[en]</center></div>
              <label class="name">
                <textarea id="tekst1" name="tekst_en"></textarea>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="coll-big">
              <div class="txt-form"><center>Tekst[de]</center></div>
              <label class="name">
                <textarea id="tekst2" name="tekst_de"></textarea>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>

            <a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript: document.getElementById('contact-form') .submit()" class="btn btn-2">Dodaj!</a>

        </form>
```

And here's my php function that I've created...

```
function dodaj_novost()
{
global $mysqli;
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES utf8");
$mysqli->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
$mysqli->query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION='utf8_general_ci'");


//sanitize variables

$naslovhr = $_POST['naslov_hr'];
$naslovhr = $mysqli->real_escape_string($naslovhr);

$nasloven = $_POST['naslov_en'];
$nasloven = $mysqli->real_escape_string($nasloven);

$naslovde = $_POST['naslov_de'];
$naslovde = $mysqli->real_escape_string($naslovde);

$teksthr = $_POST['tekst_hr'];
$teksthr = $mysqli->real_escape_string($teksthr);

$teksten = $_POST['tekst_en'];
$teksten = $mysqli->real_escape_string($teksten);

$tekstde = $_POST['tekst_de'];
$tekstde = $mysqli->real_escape_string($tekstde);


//sanitize variables END

$dan = date('d');
$mjesec = date('M');
$godina = date('Y');

$sql="INSERT INTO novosti (naslovhr, nasloven, naslovde, teksthr, teksten, tekstde, dan, mjesec, godina) VALUES ($naslovhr,$nasloven, $naslovde,$teksthr,$teksten,$tekstde,$dan,$mjesec,$godina)";
$query = $mysqli->query("$sql");


//Add picture!

    $valid_exts = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); // valid extensions
    $max_size = 2048 * 1024; // max file size (200kb)
    $path = 'uploads/'; // upload directory

    if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
        for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['image']['name']); $i++){
            if( @is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i]) )
                {
                    // get uploaded file extension
                    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
                    // looking for format and size validity
                    if (in_array($ext, $valid_exts) AND $_FILES['image']['size'][$i] < $max_size)
                    {
                        // unique file path
                        $filename = uniqid(). '.' .$ext;
                        // move uploaded file from temp to uploads directory
                        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i], $path.$filename))
                        {
                            $status = $path.$filename;
                            $link = 'http://'.$domena.'/'.$path.'/'.$filename;
                            $upit = "INSERT INTO slike_novosti (link, id_posta) VALUES ($link, $id_posta)";
                            $upit = $mysqli->query("$upit");
                            if ($upit == 'true'){
                                echo 'Successfull!';
                            } else {
                                echo 'Not sucessfull!';
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            $status = 'Upload Fail: Unknown error occurred!';
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        $status = 'Upload Fail: Unsupported file format or It is too large to upload!';
                    }
                }
                else{
                        //image is not uploaded!
                        $status = ' ';
                    }

                echo '<br>'.$status.'<br>';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Nema slike!';
    }

//Add picture END!!
```

}

And for some reason this code is still not working, If someone can point me in right direction on how to solve this problem.. I would be soo happy! :) Cheers.

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability. Lovely cargo-cult programming (`"$var"`)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first:

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO slike_novosti (slika, link_slike) VALUES ('$link_slike','$slika')";
```

check order of your variables? I think, it must be:

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO slike_novosti (slika, link_slike) VALUES ('$slika','$link_slike')";
```

at second: Use PDO component, you have a very bad code and SQL Injection.

Comment: And mysql_xxx is deprecated

Comment: @BaBL86 Still not working :S Can you check out my whole code? Thanks.

Comment: INSERT INTO slike_novosti ... $id_posta - where are you get this variable? I think, you're need to add last_insert_id from your previous query. After you have normal insert with both good variables - check tables, are they not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single qoutes from your `$variables`. For PHP '$var' is a variable with the value of $var. If you want them qouted, use "$var". See [variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

So this wil work

```
$sql="INSERT INTO novosti (naslovhr, nasloven, naslovde, teksthr, teksten, tekstde, 
         link_slike, dan, mjesec, godina) VALUES  
         $naslovhr,$nasloven,$naslovde,$teksthr,
         $teksten,$tekstde,$link_slike,$dan,$mjesec,$godina)";
```

Comment: It's probably the problem with my form, because this if (isset($_FILES['image'])) is not true